# Can't get token from my Oauth server

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

**I created an Oauth 2.0 server and a client with Spring Boot. This is my project on** [GitHub](https://github.com/igoryurenko/oauth).

**But I can't get token from oauth server.**

**Server logs:**

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

............

```
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/access_token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@6a55ed36, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http:/ /localhost:8789/server/login'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed`
```

**Client logs:**

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login/my'; against '/login/facebook'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login/my'; against '/login/my'
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Retrieving token from ht tp://localhost:8789/server/oauth/access_token
g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[4597x5], redirect_uri=[h ttp://localhost:8788/login/my]}
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-17 18:39:43.229 ERROR 23430 --- [nio-8788-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: An OAuth 2 access token must be obtained or an exception thrown.
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]`
```

....

Comment: Spring Security gives you - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

Comment: I tried to make SecurityContextHolder global, but it didn't help.

Comment: Look into the http://jhipster.github.io/. It is a good seed app generator and OAuth is a security option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I didn't protect all server resources by spring security, now it works well. You could review changes in my project if you want details.